# How to insert new lines when editing some script with fish's built-in editor?

Tags: fish

When inputing multiline script in fish shell, e.g. I have input these script

```
$ for file in *.txt
    echo $file
  end
```

and my caret is after the word `end`. Now I want to insert a line before it, make it like:

```
$ for file in *.txt
    echo $file
    echo "hello"   // I want to insert this line
  end
```

But I found if I move my caret up and after `echo $file`, and press `enter`(or `cmd/option/ctrl+enter`), it just run the entire script without inserting a new line. I have to copy them to another editor and copy back after editing.

Is there any way to do it?

---

Update:

I just uploaded a screen recording https://asciinema.org/a/i7pOWhpdXUu0RLVOAMjVJTXbn. In the recording, I moved my caret up to after `echo` and pressed `option + enter`, but it executed the script instead of inserting a new line

Comment: try alt+enter  .

Comment: FWIW, In general if I need to do non-trivial editing I just press [alt-e] or [alt-v] (they're normally both bound to the `edit_command_buffer` function) to just drop into my usual editor. When you exit the editor the buffer will automatically be reloaded. No need to copy/paste.

Comment: @glennjackman I'm on mac, and `option+enter` doesn't work, it behaves like `enter` -- to run the entire script

Comment: Thank you so much for asking this, I had been frustrated by this for years and finally was curious enough to search for "fish how to edit script without executing" and this question came up and the answers were useful to solve for me on Linux (`alt+enter` ftw!).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

fish binds escape + newline to unconditionally insert a newline. On a Mac, you would typically press option + return. However Mac terminal emulators do not send an escape-newline by default. With iTerm2 you can request that option acts as escape, under Preferences->Profiles->Keys:

[image: option to send escape]

Now the binding will be active and option-return will unconditionally insert a newline.

(You could instead add a key mapping for just this case if you prefer.)

You can confirm what the terminal receives from the emulator with `fish_key_reader` which is installed alongside fish.

Comment: ALT+Return in Linux. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @ridiculous_fish you mention you could add a key mapping for just this case, but how should that key mapping work? If I use "Send Escape Sequence", I cannot use the Return key, as it closes the modal.

Comment: I would probably just emit the key sequence esc + N or something. It doesn't have to contain a newline.

Answer (score 5):

In the default bindings, Alt-Enter will always insert a new line:

```
> bind|fgrep \\n
bind \e\n commandline\ -i\ \\n
bind \e\r commandline\ -i\ \\n
...
```

Depending on your system configuration, the Enter/Return key may send either a newline character (`\n`) or a carriage-return character (`\r`), so that's why there's two entries.

Comment: please see my updated question, I added some information and a screen recording